# ScrolledPanel with vertical scrollbar only and WrapSizer

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, sizer

I uses a `WrapSizer` in order to have an automatic layout (as thumbnail gallery) like this (see screenshot on the *left*) :

[image]

I would like that if there are two many elements, a (vertical only)-`ScrollBar` is added on the panel (see right screenshot). **How to add such a vertical scrollbar to a panel using a WrapSizer?**

---

I tried by mixing `WrapSizer` and `ScrolledPanel`, but I cannot get the desired layout.

```
class MyPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#f8f8f8')
        sizer = wx.WrapSizer()
        self.SetupScrolling()

        # add some widgets btn1, btn2, etc. in the WrapSizer
        sizer.Add(btn1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

reset the width of the scroll panel virtual size to the displayable size.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class MyPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.VSCROLL)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#f8f8f8')
        self.sizer = wx.WrapSizer()
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x = False)
        self.parent = parent

        self.addButton(self.sizer , 10)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer )
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onSize)

    def onSize(self, evt):
        size = self.GetSize()
        vsize = self.GetVirtualSize()
        self.SetVirtualSize((size[0], vsize[1]))

        evt.Skip()

    def addButton(self, sizer, num):
        for i in range(1, num):
            btn =wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, "btn"+str(i), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    MyPanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Ok but when you increase width, then if you decrease width, the panel/sizer don't resize to smaller... (it stays enlarged) Any idea ?

Comment: Another problem now ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438844/wrapsize-and-scrollbar-widgets-not-drawn-at-startup-wont-draw-later  ... WrapSizer + Scrollbar needs a lot of struggling ;)

Comment: A small thing @Jerry_Y : do you know how to modify the `top left` margin (in order that element are not too close of the top left border) ?

Comment: What I know is to modify the border around the element. code: boxSizer.Add( self.button, 0, wx.BOTTOM|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 5 );  You can try this to add a button into boxSizer in a panel. Choose the flag to control which you want to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot to include

```
self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Since the WrapSizer takes the whole frame, I think that will work. Also, instead of SetupScrolling, you can use

```
self.SetScrollRate(horiz, vert)
```

to specify the increment (in pixels, i think) of the scroll, and that should work.

I can't test it here right now though, and WrapSizers are a little weird - they sometimes have trouble figuring out their proper size. You may need to wrap it in a BoxSizer going the other direction.