# wxPython : wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel Scrollbars overlapping buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, layout, wxpython, wxwidgets

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660325/wxpython-scroll-panel-spacing-issue) question I got help with the wxPython ScrolledPanel panel, which really helped, but I have noticed that the scrollbar is interfering/overlapping with the buttons I am creating.  Is there a way to get this to stop?

Code:

```
class ScrollyPanel(wxScrolledPanel.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wxScrolledPanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.VSCROLL,
            size=(200,200))
        self.__sizer = wx.WrapSizer()
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x = False, scroll_y = True)

        self.addButton(200)
        self.SetSizer(self.__sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onSize)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()

    def addButton(self, num):
        size = wx.Size(200, 100)

        for i in range(1, num):
            btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "btn"+str(i), size = size,
                style = wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
            self.__sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 2)

    def onSize(self, evt):
        size = self.GetSize()
        vsize = self.GetVirtualSize()
        self.SetVirtualSize((size[0], vsize[1]))

        evt.Skip()
```

Issue I am seeing:
[image]

Is there a way to add padding so the scrollbars aren't overlapping the buttons?

Thank you

xxx

Comment: why do you need to use WrapSizer? Try wx.FlexGridSizer one. You can choose the number of column/rows and also the padding between rows/columns.

Comment: how do I make it expand if the window is expanded then please?

Comment: you don't need to - it is sizer responsibility.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it... self.__sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer() are buttons on a single row (going off the screen).

Comment: check the documentation. You can set number of rows and number of columns in the constructor. And then use "AddGrowableRow()/Column()" in the code.